# Paint peeling in humid old house

Tags: paint, old-house, humidity, interior

Houses, mainly built with bricks, in my hometown tend to get a lot of humidity. In some old houses, it makes bubbles in the paint and causes paint peeling.

Here are some of the pictures of places where that happens

[image]

[image]

In one of the houses the humidity problem was dealt with. Still, now the paint is peeling.

The house isn't mine, so I'm not really sure how the house was painted before. One thing I do notice is that some places there's ink on top of areas with mold before treating it, which point to some painting flaws.

How to proceed to fix the paint peeling problem?

Comment: It looks like there was a spray texture put on the walls. That may be pealing off.  Try scraping off the pealing and bubbling areas and use a moisture meter ( they aren't expensive) to see what the moisture content actually is.  This may be just poor prep or poor texture.

Comment: This is _peeling_. Chipping is the result of impact damage.

Comment: How to fix the paint peeling problem: Fix the moisture ingress problem, then repaint.

Comment: @FreeMan obviously but there are steps to be followed to prevent that from happening again. It's not to paint on top of the old paint, so the current one needs to be scrapped. Then there are different paints one can use and the order of application is also relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you need to do two things.

First, you need to control the moisture. This might mean finding a source of moisture ingress, or it might mean adding a heat recovery ventilator to the house, or it might mean adding a dehumidifier. Or it could mean all of these. Check for water in the usual places such as the roof and around the edge of the foundation. Get a humidistat if you don't already have one. Start gathering data. Then work up a plan to get the moisture to around 50% relative humidity with no wet structure or surfaces.

Second, repaint. When you repaint, do proper surface prep and use a quality primer. Most people skip one or both of these steps. Quality surface prep includes removing loose paint from the surface, adding texture so that new paint can adhere, making certain the surface is clean, and fixing any problems you find along the way. Primer isn't usually strictly necessary for interior paint, but since you are having problems with the paint coming off I suggest it.

Of course since this isn't your house, all of this might be more difficult.

Comment: I do have the dehumidifier in the area with most amount of humidity, pretty much running 24/7. It's a Cofri Dry 100. Thought of acquiring some plants for that too. The humidity is usually around 70%. Had a firm also propose a ventilator but they were asking 5k€ and the setup would take a while. Probably have to get a better dehumidifier?

Comment: In regards to the painting, still to consider. Trying to postpone that because wouldn't want to move while that happens but eventually will have to tackle it...

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres it's more important to stop the water getting in. Water is getting in to the walls somehow, that's what you need to figure out. A dehumidifier is better than nothing but it's cleaning up after the mess has already been made.